# Vimeo API - How to use the 'filter' video search parameter?

Tags: vimeo-api

The endpoint for [videos search](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#GET/videos) has the parameter 'filter' with types such as 'minimum_likes' and 'duration' but I don't see how to set a value.

For instance, if I want to search for 'live music' videos with a minimum of 100 likes, it should be something like

https://api.vimeo.com/videos?query=live+music&filter=minimum_likes

but how do I set the minimum_likes to 100? I don't see any parameter or format for this.

Answer (score 1):

To filter by minimum_likes, add an additional parameter `filter_minimum_likes` with the value. The uri should look like this:

```
https://api.vimeo.com/videos?query=live+music&filter=minimum_likes&filter_minimum_likes=100
```

Comment: Hmm when I try that I get 0 results. Without the filter there are lots of results and most of them have more than 100 likes. Weird.